# Simple ANTLR error

Tags: java, antlr, antlr3

I'm starting with **ANTLR**, but I get some errors and I really don't understand why.

Here you have my really simple grammar

```
grammar Expr;
options {backtrack=true;}

@header {}

@members {}

expr returns [String s] 
    : (LETTER SPACE DIGIT | TKDC) {$s = $DIGIT.text + $TKDC.text;}
    ;

// TOKENS
SPACE : ' ' ;
LETTER : 'd' ;
DIGIT : '0'..'9' ;
TKDC returns [String s] : 'd' SPACE 'C' {$s = "d C";} ;
```

This is the JAVA source, where I only ask for the "expr" result:

```
import org.antlr.runtime.*;
class Testantlr {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ExprLexer lex = new ExprLexer(new ANTLRFileStream(args[0]));
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lex);
    ExprParser parser = new ExprParser(tokens);
    try {
        System.out.println(parser.expr());
    } catch (RecognitionException e)  {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

The problem comes when my input file has the following content **d 9**.

I get the following error:

```
x line 1:2 mismatched character '9' expecting 'C'
x line 1:3 no viable alternative at input '<EOF>'
```

Does anyone knwos the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There  are a few things wrong with your grammar:

- lexer rules can only return `Token`s, so `returns [String s]` is ignored after `TKDC`;
- `backtrack=true` in your `options` section does *not* apply to lexer rules, that is why you get `mismatched character '9' expecting 'C'` (no backtracking there!);
- the contents of your `expr` rule: `(LETTER SPACE DIGIT | TKDC) {$s = $DIGIT.text + $TKDC.text;}` doesn't make much sense (to me). You either want to match `LETTER SPACE DIGIT` or `TKDC`, yet you're trying to grab the `text` of both choices: `$DIGIT.text` *and* `$TKDC.text`.

It looks to me `TKDC` needs to be "promoted" to a parser rule instead.

I think you *dumbed down* your example a bit too much to illustrate the problem you were facing. Perhaps it's a better idea to explain your actual problem instead: what are you trying to parse exactly?

Comment: Thanks for your answer ;)

I've removed the returns [String s], as well as the bactrack=true, but I'm still receivent the "mismatched" error.

I came up to this error while trying to do a complete date parser, with dates that could include "d C" and "a C" parts. I solved it, as you suggest, promoting the TKDC to a parser rule, but I still don't know what's wrong in a lexer rule like this one `TKDC : 'd' SPACE 'C' ;`

Comment: @xavivars, yeah, I didn't specifically mention the reason: you get the error because once the lexer "sees" `d ` (a `'d'` followed by a space), it tries to match the `TKDC` token (which isn't there). This is what I meant in the second bullet about the lexer _not_ back-tracking. Hope that clarifies it. And you're welcome, of course.

Comment: oh, so it's not possible to define "ambiguous tokens". Thanks ;)